# BeautifulSoup - Given ID how to extract other categories in div?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Using the code below extracts div that contains the number of votes on a website

```
votes = soup.find('div', {'id': 'vote_text_299159'})


<div id="vote_text_247231" class="left action_unclicked_show cursor" style="width:97px;margin-left:3px;" data-counttext="191 votes" data-actiontext="VOTE!" onmouseover="user_action_button_mouseover('vote','247231')" onmouseout="user_action_button_mouseout('vote', '247231')" onclick="loginPrompt(&#x27;vote&#x27;);clickTrack(&quot;photo_vote&quot;);">
```

Which returns the div shown below the code.

How can I extract data-counttext (or other categories) given this return and just using the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the get('attribute_name') function works here. In your case 'attribute_name' would be 'data-counttext'. Code below.

```
votes = soup.find('div', {'id': 'vote_text_299159'})
dataCountText = votes.get('data-counttext')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is regular expression approach :

```
import re
pattern=r'data-counttext="(\w.+?)"'
string_1="""<div id="vote_text_247231" class="left action_unclicked_show cursor" style="width:97px;margin-left:3px;" data-counttext="191 votes" data-actiontext="VOTE!" onmouseover="user_action_button_mouseover('vote','247231')" onmouseout="user_action_button_mouseout('vote', '247231')" onclick="loginPrompt(&#x27;vote&#x27;);clickTrack(&quot;photo_vote&quot;);">"""
match=re.search(pattern,string_1)
print(match.group(1))
```

output:

```
191 votes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag.attrs to get all the attributes of a tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
s = """<div id="vote_text_247231" class="left action_unclicked_show cursor" style="width:97px;margin-left:3px;" data-counttext="191 votes" data-actiontext="VOTE!" onmouseover="user_action_button_mouseover('vote','247231')" onmouseout="user_action_button_mouseout('vote', '247231')" onclick="loginPrompt(&#x27;vote&#x27;);clickTrack(&quot;photo_vote&quot;);">"""
soup = bs(s, "lxml")
votes = soup.find("div", {"id": "vote_text_247231"})
votes.attrs
```

output

```
{'class': ['left', 'action_unclicked_show', 'cursor'],
'data-actiontext': 'VOTE!',
'data-counttext': '191 votes',
'id': 'vote_text_247231',
'onclick': 'loginPrompt(\'vote\');clickTrack("photo_vote");',
'onmouseout': "user_action_button_mouseout('vote', '247231')",
'onmouseover': "user_action_button_mouseover('vote','247231')",
'style': 'width:97px;margin-left:3px;'}
```